# How to get td value and push,pop to an array in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get checked checkbox's row product name and push an array then if I uncheck I want to remove the product name from an array. Finally which in an array have checked checkboxes row's product name.I tried but not working.
Please help anyone.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6urvc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

app.component.ts:

```
 getProoduct(event){

 if(event.target.checked)
   {
    const target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr');

     let tdProduct= target.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').innetText;
    productArr.push(tdProduct); 
   }else{
    const target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr');

    let tdProductRemove = target.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').innetText;
    productArr.pop(tdProductRemove);  
   }

   console.log(productArr); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the product in the event handler, instead of doing complicated operations to identify the product based on dom.

**component.ts**

```
getProduct(e, product){

 if(e.target.checked)
 {
    this.productArr.push(product.product_name); 
 }
 else
 {
    this.productArr.splice(this.productArr.indexOf(product.product_name), 1);  
 }
```

**component.html**

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" (change)="getProduct($event, data)">
```

[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpvhh5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)